# Looking for a multi-processor job scheduling strategy simulator

Tags: simulation, process-scheduling

I hope this is the appropriate Stack Exchange site for questions like this.

Recently, a college student and I are looking for a robust software for simulating job scheduling in multi-processor environments, capable of generating statistics and supporting both traditional (FCFS, RR, SJF etc.) and user-created strategies.

So far, we have been able to find several published articles whose conclusions were drawn from particular and/or at least questionable snippets of code. The software we have found so far that best present the desired functionalities are [ALEA](https://github.com/aleasimulator/alea), [AnimOS](https://ess.cs.uni-osnabrueck.de/software/AnimOS/CPU-Scheduling/index.html), and [MOSS](http://www.ontko.com/moss/sched/user_guide.html).

In the search for such piece of software, we also came across ones aimed at Multiprocessor Scheduling Simulators, which are not particularly our focus (since they are focused in algorithms like G-EDF, U-EDF, NVNLF etc.), but which are worth mentioning: [SimSo](http://projects.laas.fr/simso/), [S.T.O.R.M](https://web.archive.org/web/20150620032725/http://storm.rts-software.org/doku.php), and [YARTISS](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/rtalgo/Softwares/YARTISS/).

I would like to have suggestions from you so that we can continue with our research. We are looking for professional sized software, with revised implementations and adhering to formal techniques described in the literature. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When *looking for a multi-processor job scheduling strategy simulator* (How do you simulate a strategy?) and *a robust software for simulating process scheduling in multi-processor environments [with specific capabilities]*, how are *[pieces of software] aimed at Multiprocessor Scheduling Simulators* not in focus?

Comment: @greybeard I apologize if I'm using the wrong terminology. You select the job scheduling strategy (FCFS, RR, SJF etc), configure the hardware specs (number of processors, individual clocks etc) and run those algorithms towards a custom workload. We want to evaluate different job scheduling strategies, and not multiprocessor scheduling strategies (like G-EDF, U-EDF, NVNLF etc). I hope that I made myself clear(er) now. I've also tried to improve the question. Thanks for your comment.